# Outlook web add in before send and before delete events

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I need to send data (body, location and etc.) from the appointment to my server after the user clicks on **Send** and **Delete** button.

I find solution for "Send" event in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows).

Are there any other hooks for **Send** event and can I catch **Delete** event in Outlook web add in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only hook for the **Send** event is the [On-Send feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows) you linked above. Currently, we don't have a hook for the **Delete** event. We track Outlook Add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add a request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.